# How can I complete my web-based timeline?

Tags: html, css

I am have created some portfolio/resume website using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I would like to create some timeline for my qualification section. Currently I am trying to complete my timeline. I have done the vertical lines, dots that represent the location dates for each container info in the timeline and my containers with all the info. The timeline look like broken and somehow incomplete.

Qualification section code:

```
     <section class="qualification section timeline" id="qualification">
                <h2 class="section_title">Qualification</h2>
                <span class="section_subtitle">My Personal Journey</span>
            
                <div class="qualification_container container">
                    <div class="qualification_tabs">
                        <div class="qualification_button button--flex qualification_active" data-target="#education">
                            <i class="ri-profile-line qualification_icon"></i>
                            Education
                        </div>

                        <div class="qualification_button button--flex" data-target="#work">
                            <i class="ri-briefcase-4-line qualification_icon"></i>
                            Work Experience
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="qualification_sections">
                        <!--=============== QUALIFICATION CONTENT 1 ===============-->
                        <div class="qualification_content qualification_active" data-content id="education">
                             <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 1 ===============-->
                            <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">Computer Science</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">Sofia, Bulgaria - Software University (SoftUni)</span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        May 2020 - Present
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 2 ===============-->
                            <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">Programming & Coding</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">Online - Pluralsight</span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        Aug 2019 - Present
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 3 ===============-->
                            <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">Programming & Coding</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">Online - Treehouse</span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        Nov 2017 - Jul 2019
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 4 ===============-->
                            <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">HNC/HND Computer and Systems Development - Higher Education</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">Guildford, UK - Guildford College</span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        Sep 2015 - Jun 2017
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 5 ===============-->
                            <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">BSc Architectural Design Technology</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">Coventry, UK - Coventry University</span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        Sep 2010 - Jul 2014
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 6 ===============-->
                            <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">Secondary Education Dimploma</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">Sofia, Bulgaria - “127 Iavn Denkoglu” High School,</span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        Sep 2005 - Jun 2009
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>

                        <!--=============== QUALIFICATION CONTENT 2 ===============-->
                        <div class="qualification_content" data-content id="work">
                             <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 1 ===============-->
                             <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">Accommodation Department Administrator</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">Guildford, UK - University of Surrey</span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        Mar 2017 - May 2017
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 2 ===============-->
                            <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">Crew Member</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">Guildford, UK - KFG Quickserve Limited, Burger King</span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        Apr 2015 - Sep 2016
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!--=============== QUALIFICATION 3 ===============-->
                            <div class="qualification_data timeline">
                                <div class="timeline_component timeline_component-bg">
                                    <h3 class="qualification_title">Mediaframe Ltd</h3>
                                    <span class="qualification_subtitle">UK - Administrative Assistant (short contract) </span>
                                    <div class="qualification_calendar">
                                        <i class="ri-calendar-2-line"></i>
                                        Jan 2014 - Jul 2014
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="timeline_middle">
                                    <div class="timeline_rounder"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

My css styling:

```
/*=============== QUALIFICATION ===============*/
.qualification_tabs, .volunteering_tabs{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
}

.qualification_button{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.qualification_button:hover{
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.qualification_icon{
  font-size: 1.5 rem;
  margin-right: var(--mb-0-25);
}

.qualification_data, 
.volunteering_data{
  direction: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content 1fr;
  column-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.qualification_title, 
.volunteering_title{
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.qualification_subtitle, 
.volunteering_subtitle{
  display: inline-block;
  color: var(--first-color);
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-1);
  line-height: 1.5;

}

.qualification_calendar, 
.volunteering_calendar{
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.timeline_component{
    margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

.timeline_component-bg {
  padding: 1.5em;
  background: rgba(236, 225, 249, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.timeline {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 750px;
  padding: 25px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3 1fr;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
}

.timeline_rounder{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.timeline_rounder--bottom {
  top: initial;
  bottom: 0;
}

.timeline_middle{
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgb(83, 108, 147);
  padding: 3px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 170px;
  transform: translate(6px, -7px);
}

.qualification [data-content]{
  display: none;
}

.qualification_active[data-content]{
  display: block;
}

.qualification_button, .qualification_active{
  color: var(--first-color);
}
```

My timeline look like this:

[image]

I have tried to create my timeline again by following an example from codepen that the timeline look like this:

[image]

That was unsuccessful solution as my timeline end up looking worse that the screenshot from the first image. Elements were one on top of each other and the line were not connected with some space or on top of each other. So I updated back my timeline to look like the first image. How can I fix my timeline?

Comment: Which screenshot are you trying to reproduce? Which Codepen has the code you are basing it on?

Comment: @kmoser I just don't have any idea how to complete my timeline. So I have looked at many timelines, but the one that I am referring to in my post is this link https://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/BawBzjM

Comment: Your code does not seem to match the Codepen example at all. Why don't you start with the Codepen code and add your data?